# Small issue with <hr> html tag

Tags: php, html, css

I have created vertical and horizontal lines with the `<hr>` html tag, and have them inside a PHP script. The problem I have is that when you zoom on the site, the position of the lines move.

if you zoom (command key +/-  on most browsers) the border i've made (with a div) stays in its place, but the horizontal and vertical lines do not.

Another thing I just want to mention is that I was unable to change the CSS script (stylesheet.css) because of the oscommerce 2.2 configuration.. It's a very old version of the oscommerce server and I know it would probably be a better option to upgrade the server and look into templates, but I would like to figure out my problem here.

So let's not talk about CSS since i'm not entitled to use it in this case.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <div style="width:680px;height:540px;border-radius: 20px;-webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;-o-border-radius: 20px;border:1px solid #a4a4a4;background-color:#FFFFFF;">

      <hr style="width: 0.3px; height: 480px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 660px; top: 315px;">
      <hr style="width: 0.3px; height: 480px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 890px; top: 315px;">

      <hr style="width: 610px; height: 0.3px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 468px; top: 463px;">
      <hr style="width: 610px; height: 0.3px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 468px; top: 643px;">

     <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
  </div>
```

Comment: because of position absolute

Comment: Why don't you use `border` in your table rather than inserting `hr` giving absolute postition ?

Comment: Just wanted to write the same @Rikesh, you already have a table Conor, [apply borders](http://www.somacon.com/p141.php) to it instead of using hr tags.

Comment: Oh yes I think you're right Sarfaraz, thanks for finding the problem, but now when I take out "position: absolute;" the lines don't move to the X and Y positions where I want them  (top and left attributes)  i'm wondering what I should do now

Comment: listen everybody it's not a problem to give position absolute to any tag if we give position relative to it's parent div then it will never affect in any kind i tested it and i'll always use it and that will work fine check out my answer below i have posted

Comment: Guys I don't want to apply borders since they don't look right with the rounded corners of the main border

Comment: you can handle the borders with `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggeest to add **`position:relative`** to **`parent DIV`** and change **`HR width & height`** to %

Example:

```
<div style="width:680px;height:540px;border-radius: 20px;-webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;-o-border-radius: 20px;border:1px solid #a4a4a4;background-color:#FFFFFF;position: relative">
    <hr style="width: 0.3px; height: 100%; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 33%; top: -9px;">
    <hr style="width: 0.3px; height: 100%; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 66%; top: -9px;">
    <hr style="width: 100%; height: 0.3px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 33%;">
    <hr style="width: 100%; height: 0.3px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 66%;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15"></table>
</div>
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/ybBwT/

Answer (score 1):

ok i got it problem is you use `position:absolute` and its in browser behaviour
and solution is give `position:relative` to its parent `div` and rearrange your `hr` position according to you it works i tried in browser here is your hr code i modified it according to me you modify it according to you and don't forget to give position relative to its parent div

```
<hr style="width: 0.3px; height: 480px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(51, 51, 51); position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 215px;">
<hr style="height: 480px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(51, 51, 51); position: absolute; width: 0.3px; right: 227px; top: 0px;">
<hr style="width: 610px; height: 0.3px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(51, 51, 51); position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 34px;">
<hr style="width: 610px; height: 0.3px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(51, 51, 51); position: absolute; left: 34px; top: 347px;">
```

Comment: While your code no doubt works, please try adding some punctuation to your answer. Right now it is one huge 65-word sentence, which makes it hard to read :)

Comment: @TerrySeidler oops sorry for my english :-)

Comment: hah, your english is fine, but the answer could use some of these -> `.................,,,,,,,,,,,,` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you have absolute positions in your style... Try blocking all the divs into one div and aligning the hr's with margins instead of "left" and "right"

Answer (score 0):

- Your `<hr/>` has absolute position, so it **ok** what it's stay in same place while other elements move.
- You **cannot** open `<hr/>` after `<table>` tag.

This is wrong:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">

<hr style="width: 0.3px; height: 480px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 660px; top: 315px;">
<hr style="width: 0.3px; height: 480px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 890px; top: 315px;">

<hr style="width: 610px; height: 0.3px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 468px; top: 463px;">
<hr style="width: 610px; height: 0.3px; background: #333; position: absolute; left: 468px; top: 630px;">

      </div>
```

Need to be for example:

```
<hr/>
<hr/>

<hr/>
<hr/>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <div>
           </div>
            .....
        </td>
```

- Better to use small png images instead of `hr` and make it background of `<td>`, or in last case of `<table>`